# Using Enumerable to initialize an array of arrays with the same value in C#

Tags: c#

Im new in C# I just want to know if it's possible to initialize an array of arrays with the same value using `Enumerable`, what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Select(i => {-1, -1}).ToArray();
```

or using `Repeat`

```
Enumerable.Repeat({ -1, -1}, 8).ToArray();
```

My desired output would be an array with this shape and values:

```
{{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1} };
```

1. Can this be achieved using Enumerable?
2. Is there any other "short" way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, `Repeat()` is a better choice. Again, you were close:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(new[] { -1, -1 }, 8).ToArray();
```

You only can omit the `new[]` with initializers (e.g. when declaring a variable).

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it with your first aproach, try

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Select(i => new [] { -1, -1 }).ToArray();
```